# How to get React Native AsyncStorage data File path and its Size

Tags: react-native

I need to show the `app cache size` and `data size` (clean cache) in my App. I have two questions:

1. How to get AsyncStorage data size?
2. How to Calculate the file size?

Answer (score 2):

This is the script I wrote for checking the size of AsyncStorage on disk.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Used to see the size of disk space used by React Native AsyncStorage.
#
# Works on IOS only.
#
# This script will find the most recently updated AsyncStorage location among all iOS Simulators
# and then print out the size of the folder containing AsyncStorage data. 

MANIFESTPATH=$(find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -mtime -1 -name manifest.json)
ASYNCDATADIR=$(dirname "${MANIFESTPATH}")
du -sh $ASYNCDATADIR
```

You'll get some output like this

```
28K /Users/lancedolan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04AC46D4-756D-4B68-8C54-13575B801CD8/data/Containers/Data/Application/5DFBAF7E-20DE-4CE6-926C-73D311531B36/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1
```

This is saying that my most-recently-used IOS simulator has used 28KB. A far cry from the 6MB max in Android :p

**NOTE:** Only a fraction of the total AsyncStorage data is necessarily in the manifest.json itself; the parent folder is the object of interest.